# Почему split на java не работает только с "."?

Tags: java, split

По логике длинна должна быть 3, но программа выдает 0 без ошибки

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "16.01.23";
        String[] ar = str.split(".");
        System.out.println(ar.length);
    }
}
```

при это если заменить "." на " ", "/", "-" все остальные варианты работают, подскажите что можно сделать, мне нужно именно разделение по точке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

метод `split` принимает регулярное выражение, а `.` является специальным символом, поэтому его нужно экранировать

```
str.split("\\.")
```